How to test cross chain asset transfer from Asset Hub to Parachains(Hydration)
How to test xcm transactions or cross chain asset transfer from Asset Hub to Parachains(Hydration).

Test using chopsticks + asset-transfer-api. Checkout the example mentioned here.
Chopsticks allows forking live networks and running simulations with developer accounts like Alice and Bob.
